# Problem getting html source from a protected webpage with Indy & Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, indy10

Using the Indy10 components for delphi, I am grabbing the source of a webpage and displaying it in a Memo control using the following code.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo1.Text := IdHTTP1.Get(Edit1.Text);
end;
```

When the page I am trying to display is just a normal page (ie. no login required) the results are fine, but if I try to grab the source of a page that requires a login then the result is the memo displays the source of the login page instead of the page I requested despite the fact that I am logged in to the site in both Firefox and IE browsers.

So my question is how can I "authenticate" myself with the site using the Indy components so I get the same source that I would get if I were to view the page in my browser after logging in ?

Thx,
Douglas

Comment: If the login info is saved in a cookie then you need to send such a cookie in your http headers.

Comment: I figured I might have to do something like that. I must admit the documentation for Indy is not very helpful in this situation so if you know of some examples to help get this going I would be grateful.

Comment: If the website in question uses a login page and not a real HTTP authentication response code, then there is not much you can do about it.  You will have to parse the login page's HTML, determine the necessary input values, and submit it back to the server via another Get() (or Post()) request (depending on what the login form asks for).

Answer (score 3):

You should take some time to learn how the whole HTTP thing works, because sometimes it is more complex than what it looks. A browser does a lot more than simply issuing HTTP GET or POST request with a URL, and getting back some HTML. For example they store a lot of informations about visited sites, because the HTTP headers carry a lot of  useful informations. How they do it is usually browsers specific, and not system-wide. Other browser or applications may be not able to see or use them.
You have to set up the HTTP headers properly for a given site, and handle situations like authentication. Sites with authentication can use broad range of techniques to allow access, from simple login pages to HTTP authentication methods. They can redirect you to pages that handle authentication, and although it can happen trasparently for an already logged user, a browser (or an application) will see what's happening and must handle that.

Comment: You can use tools like Wireshark or Fiddler to see what is exchanged actually.

Answer (score 1):

That is because Indy only does the transport for you.

Indy does not do the login; the website does.
There are dozens of ways a website can do a login.
Most of those logins require the support of a web-browser.

So you most likely need to simulate what a web-browser does.
That includes supporting all technologies that the web-site uses for the login.
That might include Cookies, extra HTTP headers, HTML 5, JavaScript, Flash or other features.

Be prepared for a lot of work...

--jeroen

Comment: I see and thanks for the replies everyone. I just assumed that I would need to tap into the IdCookieManager component somehow (never used it so that why I was asking) but I see there is alot to it then that. I will look into it but in the meantime I guess I will just hack something together using the TWebBrowser component (not efficient or pretty by any means but it's easy)

Comment: Indy manages cookies for you.  You do not need to do anything with TIdCookieManager yourself.  If you do not provide one, TIdHTTP creates one internally for you.